# How to limit options in a <select> based on another option selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to limit the number of options based on another selection. For instance in this example "How many credits is the class you skipped?" should be limited to equal or less than the previous question "How many total credits are you taking this semester?". So if I'm only taking 9 credits on semester the second question of how many credits I'm skipping should be equal or less than the 9 credits for the whole semester.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7tDP/1/

Here is the JS:

```
function calculateCost() {
    'use strict';
    // enter annual tuition
    var $annualTuition = parseInt($('#annual_tuition').val());
    // tuition per semester
    var semesterTuition = Math.round($annualTuition / 3);
    // total number of credits for semester
    var $semesterCredits = parseInt($('#semester_credits').val());
    // cost of a single credit
    var singleCreditCost = semesterTuition / $semesterCredits;
    // total credits for class being skipped
    var $skippedTotalCredits = parseInt($('#skipped_total_credits').val());
    // total cost for class being skipped
    var skippedTotalCreditsCost = $skippedTotalCredits * singleCreditCost;
    // number of times skipped class meets per week
    var $skippedWeekDays = parseInt($('#skipping_class_meet').val());
    // from date
    var fromDate = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
    // to date
    var toDate = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
    // calculate number of weeks in date range (semester) using 'from / to' dates
    var skippedWeeks = Math.ceil((toDate - fromDate) / (1000 * 7 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    console.log(skippedWeeks);
    // total number of days in semester for class being skipped
    //var $skippedTotalDays = parseInt($('#skipped_total_days').val());
    var skippedTotalDays = $skippedWeekDays * skippedWeeks;
    // (total cost of class) / (total number of class days in semester) = cost of class
    var skippedSingleClassCost = skippedTotalCreditsCost / skippedTotalDays;
    return skippedSingleClassCost.toFixed(2);

}

$(function() {
    'use strict';

    $('#from').datepicker({
        defaultDate: '+1w',
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function() {
            //toDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        }
    });

    $('#to').datepicker({
        defaultDate: '+1w',
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function() {
            //fromDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        }
    });

    $('#cost').on('click', function() {
        $('.costFigure').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#costTotal').html(calculateCost());

    });

});
```

Here is the html:

```
<form id="costForm" action="#" onsubmit="#">

                <div>
                    <label for="annual_tuition">What is your annual tuition (estimated)?</label>
                    <div class="styled_select">
                        <select name="annual_tuition" id="annual_tuition" value="tuition amount" autofocus>
                            <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                            <option value="5000">$5,000</option>
                            <option value="10000">$10,000</option>
                            <option value="15000">$15,000</option>
                            <option value="20000">$20,000</option>
                            <option value="25000">$25,000</option>
                            <option value="30000">$30,000</option>
                            <option value="35000">$35,000</option>
                            <option value="40000">$40,000</option>
                            <option value="45000">$45,000</option>
                            <option value="50000">$50,000</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="semester_credits">How many total credits are you taking this semester?</label>
                    <div class="styled_select">
                        <select name="semester_credits" id="semester_credits" value="" tabindex="2">
                            <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                            <option value="3">3 credits</option>
                            <option value="6">6 credits</option>
                            <option value="9">9 credits</option>
                            <option value="12">12 credits</option>
                            <option value="13">13 credits</option>
                            <option value="14">14 credits</option>
                            <option value="15">15 credits</option>
                            <option value="16">16 credits</option>
                            <option value="17">17 credits</option>
                            <option value="18">18 credits</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="skipped_total_credits">How many credits is the class you skipped?</label>
                    <div class="styled_select">
                        <select name="skipped_total_credits" id="skipped_total_credits" value="" tabindex="2">
                            <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                            <option value="3">3 credits</option>
                            <option value="6">6 credits</option>
                            <option value="9">9 credits</option>
                            <option value="12">12 credits</option>
                            <option value="13">13 credits</option>
                            <option value="14">14 credits</option>
                            <option value="15">15 credits</option>
                            <option value="16">16 credits</option>
                            <option value="17">17 credits</option>
                            <option value="18" disabled>18 credits</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="skipping_class_meet">How many times a week does the class you skipped meet?</label>
                    <div class="styled_select">
                        <select name="skipping_class_meet" id="skipping_class_meet" value="" tabindex="2">
                            <option value="0">&nbsp;</option>
                            <option value="1">1 time a week</option>
                            <option value="2">2 times a week</option>
                            <option value="3">3 times a week</option>
                            <option value="4">4 times a week</option>
                            <option value="5">5 times a week</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="dateRange clearfix">
                    <label>Between what months are you enrolled in this class?</label>
                    <div style="width: 48%; float: left;">
                        <label for="from">From:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 48%; float: right;">
                        <label for="to">To:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button id="cost" type="button">Calculate</button>
                </div>

                <div class="costFigure">
                    <h1>your missed class cost you $<span id="costTotal"></span></h1>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Comment: Here is a working solution: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/select-box-change-dependent-options-dynamically

Comment: The above answer suggested by @KaiHartmann is the best solution and a good workaround , i strongly agree and suggest the same way of using.

Comment: Creating 17 arrays seems overkill for this, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a quick function to help you out, there may be a neater way to do this, but it does the job quite nicely!

Onchange of the element `#semester_credits` I grab the value (number of semesters credits and then loop over the next select box and remove the ones that have a higher value that the chosen one, I use a global `var` to cache the removed options in case the user changes their minds and we need to add them back in.

```
$(function () {

var savedOpts = "";
$('#semester_credits').change(function() {
    //Add all options back in;
    if( savedOpts ) {
        $('#skipped_total_credits').append(savedOpts);
        savedOpts = "";
    }

    //Return false if blank option chosen;
    if( $(this).val() === "0" )
        return false;

    var chosenCreds = parseInt($(this).val());
    $('#skipped_total_credits option').each(function() {
        var thisCred = parseInt($(this).val());
        if(thisCred > chosenCreds) { 
            //Remove
            savedOpts += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Here an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7tDP/6/)

p.s the example Kai Hartmann suggests is also a nice way to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you! On Kai's example I would have to create 17 nearly identical value arrays thought wouldnt I?

Comment: @LesBallard I've amended the function slightly and updated the fiddle,  the options weren't being appended as expected, all fixed now. Glad this helped.

Answer (score 1):

On `change` of your `dropdown` fire a `onchange` trigger and on the basis of values make the 2nd `dropdown` `enable` or `disabled`.

```
$("#semester_credits").change(function () {
        var $this=this;
        $("#skipped_total_credits").children().each(function(){
            $(this).attr("disabled",parseInt($this.value) < parseInt(this.value));
        });
    });
```

Check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsss/k7tDP/4/)

**EDIT**

$this.value contains the value selected from `"semester_credits"` dropdown, now For each child of `"skipped_total_credits"`, I am checking if that value is less than the children value then make it disabled, i.e `attr("disabled", true)` else make that children enabled.

Comment: thats great! I'm going to try to understand what is going on

Comment: can you detail a little bit what is happening on this line: $(this).attr("disabled",parseInt($this.value) < parseInt(this.value));

Answer (score 0):

If you want the drop-down list for a question to change based on previous answer, you need to add an `onchange` event to each `select` element which would update another drop-down. This should then call a function which removes or adds elements in your form.

Otherwise, you can add a validation function for your `Calculate` button.